# Weakly singular integral operator well-defined and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I need to show that the weakly singular integral operator $T_\alpha$ defined by:
$$(T_\alpha f)(x)=\int_0^1|x-y|^{-\alpha}f(y)dy$$
where $0<\alpha<1$, is well-defined and bounded on $L^p([0, 1])$ for all $1 ≤ p ≤ ∞$.

I am really stuck with this problem, can someone give me some hints on how to develop the proof? $\\$
I was also wondering, is this true for $\alpha=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's begin with $p=1$.
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1|(T_\alpha f(x)|\,dx&=\int_0^1\Bigl|\int_0^1|x-y|^{-\alpha}f(y)\,dy\Bigr|\,dx\\
&\le\int_0^1|f(y)|\Bigl(\int_0^1|x-y|^{-\alpha}\,dx\Bigr)\,dy\\
&=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\int_0^1\bigl(y^{1-\alpha}+(1-y)^{1-\alpha}\bigr)\,|f(y)|\,dy\\
&\le \frac{2^\alpha}{1-\alpha}\int_0^1|f(y)|\,dy.
\end{align}$$
It is even simpler for $p=\infty$. For $1<p<\infty$ use interpolation.